# Spark 1.6 on EMR writing to S3 as Parquet hangs and fails

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, garbage-collection, emr, parquet

I'm creating an uber jar spark application that I'm spark submitting to an EMR 4.3 cluster, I'm provisioning 4 r3.xlarge instances, one to be the master and the other three as the cores.

I have hadoop 2.7.1, ganglia 3.7.2 spark 1.6, and hive 1.0.0 pre-installed from the console.

I'm running the following command:

```
spark-submit \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 4g \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 4 
--driver-memory 4g 
--driver-cores 2  
--conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g" 
--conf "spark.hadoop.spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class=org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter"  
--conf "spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.2" 
--class com.jackar.spark.Main spark-app.jar args
```

I realise that I'm not fully utilising the cluster, but at this point I'm not exactly trying to tune (or maybe that's what I should be doing?). My underlying job does something along the lines of:

1) Read parquet files from s3 that represent two datasets, run registerTempTable on the Dataframes, then run cacheTable on each. They are each about 300 mb in memory. (note: I've tried this using EMRs s3:// protocol as well as s3a://)

2) Use spark sql to run aggregations (i.e. sums and group bys).

3) Write the results to s3 as parquet files.

The jobs are running just fine when I look at the Spark UI, and they take about as long as I expect them to. The problem is that after the write-agg-to-parquet-in-s3 job finishes (Job tab), there is a period of time where no other jobs get queued up.

If I then go to the SQL tab in the Spark UI, I'll notice there is a "running query" for the same job that the Jobs tab says has completed. When I click in and look at the DAG for that query, I notice that the DAG seems to already be evaluated.

[image: DAG visualisation]

However, this query takes minutes and sometimes causes the entire spark application to restart and eventually fail...

[image: Spark UI: SQL tab]

I began to do some investigating to see if I could figure out the issue because on my Databricks trial this job is incredibly quick to execute, the DAG being identical to that on EMR (as expected). But I can't bring myself to justify using Databricks when I have no idea why I'm not seeing similar performance in EMR.

Maybe it's my JVM params? Garbage collection for instance? Time to check the executor logs.

```
2016-02-23T18:25:48.598+0000: [GC2016-02-23T18:25:48.598+0000: [ParNew: 299156K->30449K(306688K), 0.0255600 secs] 1586767K->1329022K(4160256K), 0.0256610 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2016-02-23T18:25:50.422+0000: [GC2016-02-23T18:25:50.422+0000: [ParNew: 303089K->32739K(306688K), 0.0263780 secs] 1601662K->1342494K(4160256K), 0.0264830 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2016-02-23T18:25:52.223+0000: [GC2016-02-23T18:25:52.223+0000: [ParNew: 305379K->29373K(306688K), 0.0297360 secs] 1615134K->1348874K(4160256K), 0.0298410 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2016-02-23T18:25:54.247+0000: [GC2016-02-23T18:25:54.247+0000: [ParNew: 302013K->28521K(306688K), 0.0220650 secs] 1621514K->1358123K(4160256K), 0.0221690 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2016-02-23T18:25:57.994+0000: [GC2016-02-23T18:25:57.994+0000: [ParNew: 301161K->23609K(306688K), 0.0278800 secs] 1630763K->1364319K(4160256K), 0.0279460 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]
```

Okay. That doesn't look good. [Parnew stops the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406809/parnew-gc-will-stop-the-world) and it happens every couple of seconds.

Next step, looking into the Spark UI on Databricks to see if the gc configuration is any different than EMRs. I found something kind of interesting. Databricks sets the spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to:

```
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
-javaagent:/databricks/DatabricksAgent.jar 
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-verbose:gc 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Ddatabricks.serviceName=spark-executor-1
```

Hey, I'm no gc expert and I added "learn to tune gc" to my todo list, but what I see here is more than just gc params for the executors. What does the DatabricksAgent.jar do - does that help? I'm not sure, so I force my spark job to use the java options for the executors minus the databricks specific stuff:

```
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

This doesn't change the "running query" behaviour - it still takes forever - but I do get PSYoungGen instead of Parnew (frequency is still every couple of seconds though):

```
2016-02-23T19:40:58.645+0000: [GC [PSYoungGen: 515040K->12789K(996352K)] 1695803K->1193777K(3792896K), 0.0203380 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2016-02-23T19:57:50.463+0000: [GC [PSYoungGen: 588789K->13391K(977920K)] 1769777K->1196033K(3774464K), 0.0237240 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

If you've read up to here, I commend you. I know how long of a post this is.

Another symptom I found is that while the query is running stderr and stdout are in a standstill and no new log lines are added on any executor (including the driver).

i.e.

```
16/02/23 19:41:23 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 5
16/02/23 19:57:32 INFO DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Job job_201602231940_0000 committed.
```

That same ~17 minute gap is accounted for in the Spark UI as the running query... Any idea what's going on?

In the end this job tends to restart after a few aggs get written to S3 (say 10% of them), and then eventually the spark application fails.

I'm not sure if the issue is related to the fact that EMR runs on YARN while Databricks runs on a Standalone cluster or if it's completely unrelated.

The failure I end up getting after I look into the yarn logs is the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://bucket_file_stuff/_temporary/0/task_201602232109_0020_m_000000/
```

Any advice is much appreciated. I'll add notes as I go. Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002184/spark-jobs-finishes-but-application-takes-time-to-close/35032070#35032070?

Comment: As @GlennieHellesSindholt points out this appears in a number of other questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35236375/4394783. Basically the spark.hadoop.spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class needs to be set in Hadoop conf, not Spark conf; it's not taking effect in your example.  Also use s3:// or s3n://.

Comment: actually according to Amazon [you should always use s3:// on EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html)

Comment: small correction on top of @ChristopherB's comment - when setting in the spark context's hadoopConfiguration, it is enough to set "spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class" (without the spark.hadoop prefix)

Comment: @jackar did you fix this , if yes how ?  can you please suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename