# How to Set spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to set [spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration) and nothing I do seems to get the setting to take effect.

I'm trying to have many threads write to the same output folder, which would work with `org.apache.spark.sql.
parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter` since it wouldn't use the `_temporary` folder.  I'm getting the following error, which is how I know it's not working:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://path/to/stuff/_temporary/0/task_201606281757_0048_m_000029/some_dir does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$700(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:853)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:326)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:151)
```

Note the call to `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob`, the default class.

I've tried the following, based on other SO answers and searches:

1. `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(key, val)`  (this does work for settings like `parquet.enable.summary-metadata`)
2. `dataframe.write.option(key, val).parquet`
3. Adding `--conf "spark.hadoop.spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class=org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter"` to the `spark-submit` call
4. Adding `--conf "spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class"=" org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter"` to the `spark-submit` call.

That's all I've been able to find, and nothing works. It looks like it's not hard to [set in Scala](https://gist.github.com/Arnonrgo/2e94a2494698057d5b5b#file-directoutputcommiter-clj) but appears impossible in Python.

Answer (score 4):

The approach in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589176/spark-1-6-on-emr-writing-to-s3-as-parquet-hangs-and-fails) definitively worked for me:

```
16/06/28 18:49:59 INFO ParquetRelation: Using user defined output committer for Parquet: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter
```

It was a lost log message in the flood that Spark gives, and the error I was seeing was unrelated. It's all moot anyway, since the DirectParquetOutputCommitter has been [removed from Spark](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201604.mbox/%3Ce74668802c884a7b84e717645fb8500c@git.apache.org%3E).

Comment: can you please suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename